# Unable to see files in Ubuntu VM shared folder

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, shared-folders, tftp

I am using Try Ubuntu on a VM, I have not installed it yet as I'm not sure it will work for me.

I created a shared folder in the VM [shared folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA30m.png)- in my windows `C:\Users\sfox\documents\images` with `Access Full AutoMount Yes` at `/srv/tftp`

I put 2 or 3 files in the images folder on my windows pc
but when I type `ls -lah /srv/tftp` on the VM I dont see any files.

I rebooted the VM after setting the shared folder and I use the following commands each time I start up the VM:

`sudo apt install net-tools`

`sudo apt -y install tftp-server`

`sudo systemctl start tftpd-hpa`

I also tried this step from another post but it did not work for me:

`sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils`

`E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-guest-utils`

any help is appreciated! thanks!